# Scalding read Timestamp from parquet

Tags: scala, hadoop, parquet, cascading, scalding

Hi I am trying to read a timestamp field (datetime) from A parquet file using a case class (in a typedpipe).

The parquet file is from an impala table.

the parquet-tools lib gives the type as

> optional int96

Does anyone know what the field type should be ?

If I use Option[Long]

```
case class Columns(request_id:Option[String],datetime: Option[Long])
 val input = TypedParquet[Columns](input1)
```

then it gives the below error

> Caused by: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: The
>   requested schema is not compatible with the file schema. incompatible
>   types: optional int64 datetime != optional int96 datetime

which kind of makes sense.

If I try to use BigInt

```
case class Columns(request_id:Option[String],datetime: Option[Bigint])
 val input = TypedParquet[Columns](input1)
```

It does not even compile it gives the below error

> Parquetreadsupport - could not find implicit value for parameter

Comment: Could you be able to add more explanation or code ?

Comment: I would guess some sort of date type, probably `java.sql.TimeStamp`